# Python.Pandas. Как записать в excel

Tags: python, excel, циклы, pandas, dataframe

Есть код, который их excel файла считывает данные по столбцу метка все ненулевые значения:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tab=pd.read_excel('primer.xlsx')
n_well=len(tab.columns)/5-1

for i in range(1,n_well+2):
    i=(i-1)*5+1
    skv_2=pd.read_excel('primer.xlsx','er',parse_cols=[i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5])
    skv_2drop=skv_2.drop([0,1,2])
    met_skv_2=skv_2drop[skv_2drop[i]!=0]
    met_skv_3=met_skv_2[met_skv_2[i]!=9999]
    met_skv_3.to_excel('metki1.xlsx',sheet_name='er')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как записать все данные из цикла? А то при использовании `met_skv_3.to_excel('metki1.xlsx',sheet_name='er')`
в файл записываются последние элементы цикла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по-моему проще будет объединить все DataFrame's в один и записать этот объединённый DF в Excel

Comment: Еще я бы не перечитывал Excel в цыкле - можно просто выбирать нужный диапазон столбцов из `tab` DF. Если выложите куда-нибудь свой Excel файл я мог бы набросать рабочий вариант...

Comment: @MaxU http://dropmefiles.com/KJfVT вот файл.

Comment: @MaxU дело в том, что задача стоит так, что данных диапазонов может быть и не 19 штук, как у меня, а может и больше. Кроме как цикла не имею понятия как делать, и желательно чтобы данные каждого из диапазонов выводились также, как и в исходном файле

Comment: Результат вы хотите записать в вертикальном виде (т.е. блоки по пять столбцов один __под__ другим) - я вас правильно понимаю?

Comment: @MaxU нет, наоборот, в горизонтальном(и желательно без индексов). И похоже я понял работу цикла, при использовании met_skv_3.to_excel('metki1.xlsx',sheet_name='er') в цикле, он записывает данные в файл по датафреймам друг на друга, и следовательно в файле сохраняются данные по последнему блоку. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли такой способ, чтобы блоки записывались последовательно друг за другом, а не друг на друга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант, который читает Excel файл только один раз:

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\primer.xlsx'

cols = ['label','x','y','z','value']

df = pd.read_excel(fn, skiprows=4, header=None, parse_cols='C:XFD')

dfs = []

for i in range(df.columns.size//5):
    lbl_col = 5*i
    x = df.ix[(df[lbl_col] != 0) & (df[lbl_col] != 9999), lbl_col:lbl_col+4]
    #x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product([i+1], cols)))
    x.columns = cols
    dfs.append(x.reset_index(drop=True))

result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

#result.to_excel('c:/temp/result.xlsx', startrow=3, index=True)
result.to_excel('c:/temp/result.xlsx', startrow=3, index=False)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS я хотел добавить номера пяти-столбцовых блоков (как в вашем исходном файле: 1-19), т.е. создать `multilevel columns`:

```
x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product([i+1], cols)))
```

но это пока не имплементировано:

```
NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.
```

Т.е. надо выбирать - либо многоуровневые (красивые) имена столбцов и ненужный индекс, либо нет индекса и одноуровневые имена столбцов...

PPS если нужна "шапка", то сделать это можно [подобным образом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046/5741205)

Comment: а можно еще вопрос, как из получившейся таблицы сделать проверку на наличие всех меток(т.е по первому столбцу, и если нет нео

Comment: Спасибо огромное, разобрался. А можно еще один вопрос? Как из получившейся таблицы сделать проверку на наличие всех меток(т.е. по первому столбцу) и если некоторые метки отсутствуют, то на их месте по x,y,z,value добавлять строку с этой меткой, но с каким нибудь значением(т.е. ошибкой, например 9999)?

Comment: @РамильФазлиахметов, всегда пожалуйста :) Я не совсем понял что значит "проверка на наличие всех меток"... Вы можете открыть новый вопрос и привести небольшой (5-7 строчек) пример? PS не хочется "перегружать" ответ...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582109/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE