# Проверка всех значений и добавление недостающих на место

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Как сделать проверку excel файла на наличие всех меток(по столбцу label):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, например, если нет 14ой метки, программа добавляла ее в столбец со значением 9999:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код, который выгружает данные метки, теперь нужна проверка по файлу result:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = r'C:\Users\fazliakhmetovRV\Documents\Python Scripts\primer.xlsx'

cols = ['label','x','y','z','value']

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname='er', skiprows=4, header=None, parse_cols='C:XFD')

dfs = []

for i in range(df.columns.size//5):
    lbl_col = 5*i
    x = df.ix[(df[lbl_col] != 0) & (df[lbl_col] != 9999), lbl_col:lbl_col+4]
    #x.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product([i+1], cols)))
    x.columns = cols
    dfs.append(x.reset_index(drop=True,level=1))

result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
result.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Необходимо чтобы по всем дф проходила проверка по label по наличию всех меток (1,2,3...n)(в данном случае их 15)(Т.е. некоторых меток в файле может и не быть) . И если программа не находит определенную метку, то на месте где она должна быть записывается строка с этой меткой со значением 9999

Comment: А как понять какой набор меток является эталонным? Тот в котором максимальное число меток?

Comment: @MaxU да, максимальный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот исправленная версия:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = r'C:\Users\fazliakhmetovRV\Documents\Python Scripts\primer.xlsx'
out = r'C:\Users\fazliakhmetovRV\Documents\Python Scripts\out.xlsx'

cols = ['label','x','y','z','value']

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname='er', skiprows=4, header=None, parse_cols='C:XFD')

dfs = []

for i in range(df.columns.size//5):
    lbl_col = 5*i
    # filter each 5-column block
    x = df.ix[(df[lbl_col] != 0) & (df[lbl_col] != 9999), lbl_col:lbl_col+4]
    # set custom column names
    x.columns = cols
    # set 'label' column as index (will be used for alignment by `pd.concat()`) 
    x.index = x.label
    dfs.append(x)

# merge filtered DFs horizontally (aligned by indexes)
result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# replace all `label` columns with the "most complete" list of labels
result.ix[:, ::5] = pd.concat([result.index.to_series()] * (len(df.columns)//5), axis=1)
# replace all NaN's with `9999`
result.fillna(9999, inplace=True)
# save resulting DF to Excel
result.to_excel(out, index=False)
```

out.xlsx:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS как работает [DataFrame.ix[...]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   a  b  c
0  4  9  8
1  8  4  5
2  7  9  4
3  4  7  1
4  0  7  3
5  8  1  4
6  1  9  8
7  4  9  3
8  1  3  8
9  7  9  0
```

для того, чтобы отфильтровать (выбрать) строки, в которых `a > 1` и `b < 8`:

```
In [28]: df.ix[(df.a > 1) & (df.b < 8)]
Out[28]:
   a  b  c
1  8  4  5
3  4  7  1
5  8  1  4
```

теперь тоже самое, но выбрать только столбцы `['a','b']`:

```
In [29]: df.ix[(df.a > 1) & (df.b < 8), ['a','b']]
Out[29]:
   a  b
1  8  4
3  4  7
5  8  1
```

Comment: спасибо, помогли) можно уточняющий вопрос? что делает .ix -  он фильтрует значения по столбцу? или как он вообще прорабатывает?)

Comment: @РамильФазлиахметов, добавил демо в ответ...